# Which is a better approach, using 2 sub-reports or 2 tablix in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I have 2 different data sources, and data from both the sources needs to be displayed on a single page.
There are 2 different approaches for this, 
 - using 2 different tablix, where each tablix will be linked to a different data source and 
 - using 2 subreports, where each sub report is a seperate report which is referenced into the main report.

Which is a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Question is opinion based so I will add my 2 cents.
I heavily use SSRS and I really like using it.
If you are happy to use 2 tablix on a page and can combine/adjust showing relevant data then go for it.

But if you wish to keep logic/ data separate in two reports then go for subreport.
Personally I like and use subreport a lot. I use them mostly when my data becomes complex and I want to show data in a single table.
But you should also consider maintaining 2 reports in this case and also you should have to check/dependencies on child and parent report.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to display both reports on a single page, you should just use two tablix, one for each of your data source.